# Introducing Blended Wordtails

Tags: word, wordplay

The [Vowelburger](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=vowelburger) restaurant franchise has a new competitor: a drinks bar called Blended Wordtails. Each day, they offer a different selection of their patented Blended Wordtail drinks, every one of which has its own tagline for the confused customer. Today's menu looks like this, with every drink worth £6.00:

| Blended Wordtail | Tagline |
| --- | --- |
| ???? | Every third person's choice. |
| ???? | You're guaranteed to notice it. |
| ???? | Last chance, this variety is about to terminate. |
| ???? | Unique garden herb sprigs in all drinks. |
| ???? | So good you'll mail your friends about it. |
| ???? | Wins first place in every Novelty Drinks Table. |

Can you help to sort out these drinks? I want to know their names as well as their taglines before I make an order, so that I can figure out the ingredients.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that each Blended Wordtail:

> is an **anagram** (i.e. 'blended') of the same set of 4 letters.

This means the menu should read as follows:

> Every third person's choice = **OPTS** (he/she/it *chooses*)
>  You're guaranteed to notice it = **SPOT** (notice = spot)
>  Last chance, this variety is about to terminate = **STOP** (terminate = stop)
>  Unique garden herb sprigs in all drinks = **POTS** (herbs = potted plants)
>  So good you'll mail your friends about it = **POST** (mail = post)
>  Wins first place in every Novelty Drinks Table = **TOPS** (first place = 'tops' the table)

First round's on me!

<sub>PS One minor observation:</sub>

> <sub>Possibly a coincidence, but I like to think that the price of £6.00 has been deliberately chosen because these 4 letters are worth **6 points** together in a game of Scrabble...! (P=3,O/S/T=1)</sub>

Comment: That was fast! Nicely done.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks :) I've added one minor observation which I don't know if it was deliberate, but it certainly fits nicely within the puzzle...!

Comment: Absolutely deliberate, good catch :-) The phrases "confused customer" and "sort out" are also not coincidences.