# Another Round of Blended Wordtails

Tags: word, wordplay

The [Blended Wordtails](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/110244/5373) drinks bar has a new selection on offer! Each day, they offer a different range of their patented Blended Wordtail drinks, every one of which has its own tagline for the confused customer. Today's menu looks like this, with every drink worth £5.00:

| Blended Wordtail | Tagline |
| --- | --- |
| ????? | Garden flower provided in all drinks. |
| ????? | So beautiful you'll just look at it rather than drinking. |
| ????? | Every single review values it highly. |
| ????? | The glass alone indicates its value. |
| ????? | The best solution when you're emotional. |
| ????? | So good it will shock your system. |

Can you help to sort out these drinks? I want to know their names as well as their taglines before I make an order, so that I can figure out the ingredients.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Garden flower provided in all drinks.

> ASTER

So beautiful you'll just look at it rather than drinking.

> STARE

Every single review values it highly.

> RATES

The glass alone indicates its value.

> [TARES](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tare) (2nd definition is relevant here, I think).

The best solution when you're emotional.

> TEARS

So good it will shock your system.

> TASER

Comment: Well done! The word you're missing is the most ... obscure of them all, but I was hoping it'd be solved by correctly figuring out what's an anagram of all the others. **Edit:** oh, you edited before my comment went through :-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was your "in" to this puzzle - which clue was easiest to solve?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thank you, the second line was the "in" for me and I figured it would be a word that used more common letters.